# how to highlight underscored text

Tags: ms-word

Does anyone know how I can highlight uderscored text in MS Word? I need to find all instances of underscored text but it seems that I can't do that. The only option available is to find hightlighted text so I decided to highlight all instances of underscores and then find them.

Comment: Does Word allow a disjoint selection? I've never seen it.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Yes, disjoint selections are possible - e.g. select text with the same formatting using the Home tab->Editing group->Select->Select text with similar formatting. But it is not always obvious how to work with such a selection - e.g. you can successfully set the whole selection to Italic using Selection.Font.Italic = True, but I don't think there is a way to iterate through the separate parts of the Selection, and e.g.  Len(Selection) retrieves the length of the last selected chunk, not the whole selection.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223084(v=office.11).aspx) says that the `Selection` object has a `Sections` property; perhaps that's what's needed to iterate through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use find & replace.

- find field blank, *Format* button, set underlined font
- replace fiels blank, again *Format* button, set Hihlighting

Color of highlighting is the current color visible in highlight button.

Answer (score 1):

If I highlight an underlined word and right-click, one of my choices under Styles is "Select text with similar formatting", which highlights all underlined text.  Might not work if your document has many styles, but it's worth a try.